# My first Excel Office JS Add-in ActiveX issue

Tags: excel, office-js

I've started experimenting with my [first Excel Office JS Add-in](https://hongbo-miao.gitbooks.io/excel/content/tutorial/build-your-first-excel-add-in.html)
but keep getting a security message every time I reload the add-in.
I've tried the different options in Excel Trust Center settings with no result.
Can anyone help me with this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you double-check what is the URL that you put into your manifest.  In particular, is it a https://localhost:XXXXX/ sort of URL?

If I recall correctly, I've seen something similar before when using http (rather than http**s**), and/or when I tried using a `file:///` path.

Comment: I've moved my html file to localhost location under Apache webserver
and changed in the manifest file from
`<SourceLocation DefaultValue="C:/Users/scorpion/Documents/addin/Home.html" />` 
to `<SourceLocation DefaultValue="http://localhost/addin/Home.html"/>`

This works without security warning.
Thanks for your help.

ps: only I don't understand why I can't place files in My Documents for local use only.

Comment: Glad it helped.  Add-ins expect to be hosted on a real browser (http, or ideally https if you also want to test on Online), a file url will not behave the way you want.  Nor would it work in Online.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveX is a legacy technology and shouldn't be leveraged by an Office Web Add-in.

Aside from its age, only IE10 supports ActiveX (and its disabled by default) which means any Add-in that uses ActiveX will fail to work in anything other than Office for Windows. All other platforms (Office for Mac, Office Online, Office for iOS, etc.) would be unable to use it.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveX controls are disabled in Office add-ins by design and security.
thanks!